# Getting the email from a form in Sitecore EXM

Tags: exm

The team wants to use sitecore forms for its site's transaction. One of the requirements is to use sitecore's Automated email campaign to send the confirmation email of a successful registration.

How can we use the email from the text input field to send the confirmation email?

We have no idea as of the moment how this can be achieved.

Thanks,

Hanz Enriquez

Answer (score 2):

You could check the Forms Extension my colleague Bart released: https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions. It includes save actions implementing some missing features (for now) in the Forms/EXM combination. For instance, sending a mail to someone that is not your current contact and sending the forms data to EXM.

It might do what you need, and if not you can use the codebase as a starting point for your implementation. For your purpose, you'll need to check his SendEmail submit action. The full code is a bit too much to copy here, but it actually combines existing features of Forms and EXM to something useful.

The official docs on how to create a custom save action can be found here: https://doc.sitecore.net/web_forms_for_marketers/81/working_with_actions_and_validations/save_actions/create_a_new_save_action

Comment: Thanks @Gatogordo.  I will try this as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible out of the box.

However, I have written a module "Sitecore Form Extensions" that will add this functionality. 
https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions/tree/master/downloads
http://onelittlespark.bartverdonck.be/send-sitecore-forms-to-a-fixed-email-address/

There is a new "Send Email" submit action in the package that allows you to pick an EXM message, in the EXM message you can use tokens in the format of $form_fieldname$

Comment: Thanks @Bart I will try this out and will let everyone know about the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The Automated email campaign will attempt to send the email to the current contact. The missing piece in Sitecore 9 Forms is populating the contact with the data from the form.
You can implement a custom Submit Action to identify the contact and send all form fields into xDB. Then, the automated campaign will pick up the details and send the email.

Here's a detailed walk-through of how to create a custom submit action that will populate contact details: 
https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/sitecore_forms/setting_up_and_configuring/walkthrough_creating_a_custom_submit_action_that_updates_contact_details

Comment: Thanks @Elena. I will look into your solution as well.

Comment: In line with this doc, I also provided a demo of it during Virtual Developer Day.  https://sitecorehacker.com/2018/02/22/svdd-using-forms-in-sitecore-9-and-xdb-together/